# Can not resolve onCreate method for SherlockFragmentActivity in Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I managed to integrate the ActionBarSherlock library to my project in Android Studio. Here is the [tutorial](http://showlabor.blogspot.ca/2013/05/actionbarsherlock-in-android-studio-01.html) I followed.

But I got a strange problem. I got "Can not resolve onCreate method" error message although I still can run the application (Please look at the red color, it means an error and there are a lot of this kind of error in this project.)

[image]

Does anybody have idea what's wrong with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using maven remote dependecies. Local dependencies for support lib and ABS is not needed anymore.
Change the dependencies to this in your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.+@aar'
}
```

And press the `sync project from gradle` button. Then rebuild your project.

Comment: Does this mean I don't need to download ABS and add to my project anymore? And where is the sync project from gradle button? Is it in File->Synchronize?

Comment: And I got the following error message.

Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MySherlockActionBar:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.

Comment: right. most common library projects are located in a maven repo somewhere. support lib and google play services can be downloaded via sdk manager. ABS is on maven central. A lot other OOS libraries are locateted on github: https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/. syncing: there is a button. but you can go by project -> android -> snyc from gradle

Comment: well, then see the console for more info. ;)

Comment: This is the simplest solution by far. I even don't need to download ActionBarSherlock. But I have a question. Does this mean I have to be online everytime when I compile my project?

Comment: Gradle is caching all the dependencies. There is a switch for gradle's command line for offline usage.

Comment: I've tested by turning off my wifi and remake the project. It's still working. That means it's really cached somewhere. I don't know where the switch you mentioned is. Sorry, I'm new in Android Studio and Gradle.

Comment: Things are cached in $HOME/.gradle and I think gradle hast literally a --offline switch.